# Join two tables and calculate fields in result

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

There is 2 tables in SQL Server 2008/2012 DB. 
First table is **table1**, where field m1 has summary values (as a counter) - on 2014-12-15 13:00:00 its have 10000 real value (80000 - 70000) and have factor 1, **p1** field have already real data with factor 0.01 - on 2014-12-15 13:00:00 its value equal 10.89 (1089 * 0.01), fiel V1 have real data and factor 1:

```
| DateTime            |   m1  |  p1  |  V1   |
|---------------------|-------|------|-------|
| 2014-12-15 08:00:00 | 45000 | 1045 | 23.45 |
| 2014-12-15 09:00:00 | 51000 | 1078 | 25.78 |
| 2014-12-15 10:00:00 | 58000 | 1056 | 24.99 |    
| 2014-12-15 11:00:00 | 62000 | 1069 | 27.34 |    
| 2014-12-15 12:00:00 | 70000 | 1045 | 29.90 |  
| 2014-12-15 13:00:00 | 80000 | 1089 | 28.67 |
```

Second table is **table2** have field m2 have real data with factor 1, field p2 have real data with factor 0.01, field V2 have summary data and factor 0.1:

```
| DateTime            |  m2 |  p2  |  V2   |
|---------------------|-----|------|-------|
| 2014-12-15 08:00:00 | 456 | 2045 | 34500 |
| 2014-12-15 09:00:00 | 480 | 2080 | 35600 |
| 2014-12-15 10:00:00 | 495 | 2090 | 35900 |    
| 2014-12-15 11:00:00 | 445 | 2056 | 36700 |    
| 2014-12-15 12:00:00 | 458 | 2076 | 37200 |  
| 2014-12-15 13:00:00 | 478 | 2067 | 38000 |
```

**And I would in result of query such table**:

```
| DateTime            |   m1  |   p1  |  V1   |  m2 |   p2  |  V2   |
|---------------------|-------|-------|-------|-----|-------|-------|
| 2014-12-15 08:00:00 | ----- | 10.45 | 23.45 | 456 | 20.45 | ----- |
| 2014-12-15 09:00:00 | 6000  | 10.78 | 25.78 | 480 | 20.80 |  110  |
| 2014-12-15 10:00:00 | 7000  | 10.56 | 24.99 | 495 | 20.90 |  30   |     
| 2014-12-15 11:00:00 | 4000  | 10.69 | 27.34 | 445 | 20.56 |  80   |    
| 2014-12-15 12:00:00 | 8000  | 10.45 | 29.90 | 458 | 20.76 |  50   |  
| 2014-12-15 13:00:00 | 10000 | 10.89 | 28.67 | 478 | 20.67 |  80   |
```

With which query get this result? Thanks.

Comment: I'm sorry but this question is very unclear: In your espected result you have 6000 on column m1, but that value doesn't exist on table1. Neither 7000, 4000 and so on... Please be more specific with you example so we can help you!

Comment: Wich is the field to join both tables? Or is it a calculated one?

Comment: @ericpap in field m1: 2014-12-15 09:00:00 get 51000-45000=6000, 2014-12-15 10:00:00 get 58000-51000=7000 etc. And this tables join by DateTime table

Comment: How can you join on m1 if it is not in each table?

Comment: @Blam I want to get values from this tables in one result

Comment: What do you need to join on?

Comment: @Blam Join by DateTime field, such on result table

Comment: Field m1 in table1 and field V2 in table2 are summary fields - they are store counter tick, like energy counters, they are always increase self value.

Comment: How the V2 column calculate in final table? from where you get the 110, 30 ..so on value?

Comment: @Piyush V2 like m1, 2014-12-15 09:00:00 get (35600-34500) * 0.1 = 110, 2014-12-15 10:00:00 get (35900-35600) * 0.1 = 30 etc. Like m1 field to calculate current field value, get diff between current value and previos hour.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something along

```
SELECT
  CONVERT(varchar(30), T1.dateTime, 120)
  , CASE LAG (m1, 1, 0) OVER (ORDER BY m1)
      WHEN 0 THEN '-----'
      ELSE CONVERT(VARCHAR(5), m1 - LAG (m1, 1, 0) OVER (ORDER BY m1)) END AS m1
  , p1 * 0.01 AS p1
  , v1
  , m2
  , p2 * 0.01 AS p2
  , CASE LAG (v2, 1, 0) OVER (ORDER BY v2)
      WHEN 0 THEN '-----'
      ELSE CONVERT(VARCHAR(3), CONVERT(INTEGER, (v2 - LAG (v2, 1, 0) OVER (ORDER BY v2)) * 0.1)) END AS v2
FROM Table1 T1
JOIN Table2 T2
  ON T1.dateTime = T2.dateTime;
```

should work. Not sure, though, turning "m1" and "v2" into `VARCHAR` is really, what you need/want.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/8f142/18/0)

Sorry - didn't pay attention to your SQL Server version. `LAG` is, unfortunately, not available in older versions. But there are workarounds. Borrowed from [SQL SERVER – Solution to Puzzle – Simulate LEAD() and LAG() without Using SQL Server 2012 Analytic Function](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2011/11/24/sql-server-solution-to-puzzle-simulate-lead-and-lag-without-using-sql-server-2012-analytic-function/) for

```
WITH
Sub1 AS (
  SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY T1.dateTime) n,
     T1.dateTime,
     T1.m1,
     T1.p1 * 0.01 AS p1,
     T1.v1,
     T2.m2,
     T2.p2 * 0.01 AS p2,
     T2.v2
  FROM Table1 T1
  JOIN Table2 T2
    ON T1.dateTime = T2.dateTime
),
Sub2 AS (
  SELECT dateTime, m1, p1, v1, m2, p2, v2,
    CASE WHEN n % 2 = 1 THEN MAX(CASE WHEN n % 2 = 0 THEN m1 END) OVER (PARTITION BY n / 2) ELSE MAX(CASE WHEN n % 2 = 1 THEN m1 END) OVER (PARTITION BY (n + 1) / 2) END m1Lag,
    CASE WHEN n % 2 = 1 THEN MAX(CASE WHEN n % 2 = 0 THEN v2 END) OVER (PARTITION BY n / 2) ELSE MAX(CASE WHEN n % 2 = 1 THEN v2 END) OVER (PARTITION BY (n + 1) / 2) END v2Lag
  FROM Sub1
)
SELECT
  CONVERT(varchar(30), dateTime, 120) dateTime
  , CASE m1Lag
      WHEN 0 THEN '-----'
      ELSE CONVERT(VARCHAR(5), m1 - m1Lag) END AS m1
  , p1
  , v1
  , m2
  , p2
  , CASE v2Lag
      WHEN 0 THEN '-----'
      ELSE CONVERT(VARCHAR(3), CONVERT(INTEGER, (v2 - v2Lag) * 0.1)) END AS v2
FROM Sub2
ORDER BY dateTime;
```

Updated [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/8f142/14/1).

Comment: Is there exist analog of LAG command in SQL Server 2008 or 2005?

Comment: Unfortunately not. But there are workarounds. Please see updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this sample sql query. Instead of id column in sql here, use DateTime column in your table. To display the "---" in m1, and V2 column, you can replace on application level.

You can find the DEMO for this sample query [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/92ed4/1).

```
SELECT Table1.id,Table1.m1,Table1.p1,Table1.V1,
       Table2.m2,Table2.p2,Table2.V2
 FROM (
         SELECT  f.id, 
                (f.m1 - ISNULL(f2.m1,0)) AS m1,
          substring(Convert(varchar(10),(CONVERT(Numeric(6,2),f.p1)/100)),0,6) as p1,
          f.V1
          FROM t1 f LEFT OUTER JOIN t1 f2
          ON  (f2.id+1) = (f.id)
) AS Table1 
INNER JOIN (
            SELECT  f.id, f.m2,     
            substring(Convert(varchar(10),(CONVERT(Numeric(6,2),f.p2)/100)),0,6) as p2,
            (f.V2 - ISNULL(f2.V2,0)) * 0.1 AS V2
            FROM t2 f
            LEFT OUTER JOIN t2 f2
            ON  (f2.id+1) = (f.id)
           ) 
  AS Table2
  ON Table1.id = Table2.id
```